# Execute a Javascript Function Upon Submitting a Spring Form

Tags: java, javascript, spring

I have a JS function that I want to run (call an asynchronous JMS queue function) upon submitting.

Can someone point me to an example of how to do that from inside a Spring form?  I know how to do a `$(document).ready(function()`, but I only want to do this when POSTing a form submission.

Comment: I should add that I tried the onSubmit(), but that doesn't appear to fire inside a Spring form.

Comment: Can you include the code you've tried? Or, can you create a jsFiddle example of your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attaching a submit handler with jQuery:

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" action="#" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="field1" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form1').submit(function() {
    alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
  });
});
```

Regarding your use of Spring, the Spring form tag will generate a usual HTML form. You can specify an id (or class) for it and attach a handler with jQuery.
Link to an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kolchytsky/Wy47g/